# summing of several numbers with the minimum difference objective

Tags: algorithm, optimization

We have several positive and negative numbers which total sum of them become zero. For example: -2,1,-2,-2,1,2,2.
these numbers must ordered in a list such that maximum difference between summation of them in any instance minimized. For example, if we sort them as 
-2,2,1,1,-2,2,-2 summation of them becomes as: -2,0,1,2,0,2,0 resulting in maximum difference 4 (difference between -2 and 2).
One greedy algorithm (probably most simple one) can be written as:

1- put a number in the first place

2- put the next number in the list such that total sum from the first place up-to current place becomes close to zero.

3- repeat the step 2 until there is no number

Does anyone has/know optimum solution for this problem?

or Does anyone knows a similar problem which has a optimal solution?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And the right order for the sample provided is `1, -2, 2, -2, 2, -2, 1` with the difference `2` (`1 - -1`)?

Comment: Do you have to work with integers (or efficient integer values which can be scaled up to be integers, e.g. `-2/5, 1/5, -2/5, ... ,2/5`)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko ofcourse this can be right order. there are more than one solution for example: 2,-2,2,-2,1,1,-2 can be another right order

about the second question numbers are general but in the simple case I can put a constraint on input values

Comment: Let `max` be the item with max *absolute* value, e.g. `-6` in `-6, -1, 2, 2, 3` sequence. We can try to hold all partial sums within `[0..max]` or `[-max..0]`. Start with *max* (`-6`) keep adding items with *different* sign (and maximum absolute values) until you have to cross `0`, in this case start adding items with same sign (and maximum absolute values): `-6, 3, 2` then `-1` then `2` - `-6, 3, 2, -1, 2`.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you man. How we can prove optimality of this solution?

Comment: my gut sence says that there should be an *induction* proof (i.e. we can always add an item such that the next partial sum is in the `[0..max]` or `[-max..0]` range), but I can't put it clearly (that's why I've provided it as acomment, not a solution). It's easy to prove that the range has to be at least `max` (since you have to add the item with `max` absolute value somehow).